# NSNumber Leaking memory numberWithInt inside a For loop

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory

NSNumber Leaking memory inside a for loop - started occurring at Xcode Instruments version 4.1 on OSX Lion - this is leaking when executed on device profile with instruments. Any ideas appreciated.

```
        int currentActivityScore = [self.activityScore intValue];
        int deltaCriteriaScore = [[segmentItemArray objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
        int newActivityScore = currentActivityScore + deltaCriteriaScore;
        self.activityScore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:newActivityScore];
```

i tried this code too, still getting a leak!!!

```
        int currentActivityScore = [self.activityScore intValue];
        int deltaCriteriaScore = [[segmentItemArray objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
        int newActivityScore = currentActivityScore + deltaCriteriaScore;
        NSNumber *newActivityScoreNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:newActivityScore];
        self.activityScore = newActivityScoreNumber;
        [newActivityScoreNumber release];
```

Comment: Do you declare `activityScore` as `retain` or `copy`?

Comment: Do you relinquish ownership of `activityScore` in `-dealloc`?

Comment: this isn't a leak while you're pointing at it. instruments will point to the location it was created as to the "cause" of the leak, but the real *cause* is how you're not getting rid of it cleanly.  how do you dispose of this ivar?

Comment: retain. also i did not mention that this is running inside a For loop that executes 10 loops.

Comment: I call self.activityScore = nil both in the view unload and in the dealloc. I also tried doing a release but it didn't work.

Comment: Is Instruments telling you you're leaking multiple objects or just one? If you're only leaking one object, you're likely leaking the last value of self.activityScore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `activityScore` either retains or copies its values, then I think your code is okay.

It's not unheard of for Instruments to give false-positives (or miss genuine leaks). Consider it a pointer to code to double-check rather than a guarantee of a leak.

Comment: well it is providing a leak what i found is that this leak is only when i put this inside a For loop

Comment: There is no leak in the code you've shown us. Either you need to show us more code or you need to accept that this is a false-positive from Instruments.

Comment: This is what worked for me: I simply did not do the calculation inside the loop, i created local variables and only after the For loop did I assign them into the class property - this got rid of the problem

Comment: You assume that Instruments is infallible. It's not. If you've not defined a custom accessor and there's no leak in the code outside a loop, then there's no leak _inside_ a loop either.

Comment: Then how can one issue a bug to apple on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumber *newActivityScoreNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:newActivityScore];
self.activityScore = newActivityScoreNumber;
```

So here is NSNumber is autoreleased. you do not need to bother about it.

Comment: they both leak memory for me when i put this inside a loop.